# change status message on page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this code to change the status bar of IE.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onmouseover="window.status='Google';return true;">Google</a>
```

But the problem is when i'm using a menu (links inside a div) it doesn't change anymore the status bar. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What exactly is the functional requirement? This is now too ambiguous. Also, what'd you expect to happen when the mouse goes out the link?

Comment: "Can I fix this?" ... I don't know, can you?

Comment: What status bar? More info please

Comment: Please dont't manipulate the browser's status bar; it's there for a reason, if you need to show a status to the user for your app's functionality then you should really use the content area within the viewport. This is mostly personal, of course, I *loathed* -way back in the nineties- websites that messed with my window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an *awesome* solution

```
<a href="//./ Woo status bar" onclick="this.href='http://google.com'">
```

No, but really though - this practice this a little outdated. Users expect to be able to see the URL of the link they're about to click to ensure it is legit. If you want to give people more information about a link, encode it either in the paragraph (eg: "take a look at [this big search engine](http://google.com) or [this up-and-coming one](http://bing.com)"), or use the `title` attribute on the link. The text you enter there will appear in a tooltip if the user hovers on the link.

Comment: The *awesome* solution doesn't work at all in IE6/7/8 and FF prefixes it with `file://`.

Comment: Well, it depends on where you have the file. It'll be prepended with whatever the protocol is (http, file, https...). Anyway, it was kinda meant as a joke.

Answer (score 3):

Most modern browsers allow the user to decide, if she wants the status bar being overwritable. If it is disabled (which is, I assume, the default in many browsers), you have no way to bypass this (other than finding a zero day exploit).

Answer (score 1):

```
onmouseover="window.status='Google';
```

works only for IE. It doesn't seem to work for FF. What browser are you testing it?

Comment: i'm using Internet Explorer 8

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, this works in only IE but it won't work for other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" onmouseover="$(this).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com')" onmousedown="$(this).attr('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com/')">Link 4</a>
```

This worked for me on Chrome/IE(7/8)/FF.